# Highest frequency of Flashlight in Android Device

Tags: android, android-ndk, led, flashlight

I'm making a application that can use flashlight as a VLC (Visible light communication) device. Which means I need a really **High frequency**. I've tried both android.hardware.Camera and newest API setTorchMode().But both of them need a minium 2ms to open the FlashLight.
So my question is: Can I get a higher frequency with NDK?